# Creating File using extension firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, add-on

I am trying to create a file in my extension directory and I have this code:

```
AddonManager.getAddonByID(" extension id here ", function(addon)
{
    var uri = addon.getResourceURI("hello.txt");
    var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"]
            .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
    var stringUri = uri.asciiSpec;
    stringUri = stringUri.replace(new RegExp(/\//g), '\\');
    stringUri = stringUri.slice(8);
    alert(stringUri);
    try{
        file.initWithPath(stringUri);
    } catch(e) {
        alert(e);
    }
    alert(addon.hasResource("hello.txt"));
});
```

For some reason, the last alert shows always false and file doesn't exist. What am I doing wrong?

I also put unpack true unpack tags in the install.rdf to see my extension directory.

Comment: What's the scheme of config.json uri, `file` or `jar`?

Answer (score 0):

`initWithPath` accepts only local filesystem paths. Assuming `uri` is a file url, you can do the conversion like this

```
var path = uri.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIFileURL).file.path
```